# How to show the detailed stack trace in IIS?

Tags: c#, exception, iis

I have an application hosted in IIS, but a null reference exception occurs:

[image]

As you can see, there's no stack trace, only a general exception "object reference not set to an instance of an object" is shown

But I don't know where the exception flows.

I am unable to replace the whole directory to the server since there is some other folders there.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You can see that is crashes on `Com.Vizz.Web.Index.Page_Load` method

Comment: CustomError should be off... Did you tried?

Comment: @Zippy Yes, but it's a bit hard for me to drill down to which line the error flows, since the Page_Load have about 100 lines. :(

Comment: @AmitSoni the customerror is off, or else this exception page won't be shown, I double checked the web.config

Comment: Try with `<compilation debug="true">` in the web.config and see if it helps even though it's not recomended(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prashant_upadhyay/archive/2011/07/15/pros-and-cons-of-using-debug-true-in-asp-net-applications-in-production-environment.aspx) on production

Comment: The stack trace is clearly visible on the screenshot. What is this question about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do have access to the assemblies, then `+72` is almost enough for you to know which line of code is the cause,

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2005/01/25/funny-numbers-in-my-stack-trace.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your web.config.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="CardSpace">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.IO.Log">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.IdentityModel">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>

    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\logs\Traces.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

This outputs a more in depth trace log.  You'll need service trace viewer tool to view it.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

Since you accepted the answer that tells you to find the offending source code line I assume that's what you want.

Deploy the PDBs that the compiler generates to production. This has no performance impact and provides line numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your information, it turned out that an object in the page load wasn't signed anything so it was null